# How to get the values from php page to angular js controller

Tags: php, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am integrating the payumoney gateway, the response is in PHP, but I need to fire a API based on the response, to send the invoice to mail using angularjs. Here is my php code Thanks, If any help.

```
<?php
session_start();
$totalorder = $_SESSION['totalorder'];
?>
```

and i am able to get that value in same page as object in the body part.

i am getting the response and transaction id that is everything.

But now my query is, how to send / get those response from php page to angularjs html page or in controller.

Even i tried the global storage variable using scripts but no use. Thanks if any help.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes. I tried it to get using php session, but not able to get that object in my html page or controller.

Comment: edit your question with that code

Comment: @NitinAgarwal add what you tried in the question

Comment: Check my code once again

Comment: what does this question has to do with `angular-ui-bootstrap` ?

Comment: Buddy try to concentrate on question not on tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have did same for the Paypal. create one directive and in that directive you can post all your data in form. and set action of your PHP. so on that action Url You will able to find the parameters

steps to integrate.

1. create directive named payuMoneyButton.

   app.directive('payuMoneyButton', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',

   ```
       compile: function (element, attrs) {
           var languageCodes = [ 
               'en_US' 
           ];
           var currencyCodes = [  
               'USD'
           ];
           var buttonSizes = [ 
               'SM', // small
               'LG' // large
           ];
           var name = this.name;
           function err(reason) {
               element.replaceWith('<span style="background-color:red; color:black; padding:.5em;">' + name + ': ' + reason + '</span>');
               console.log(element.context);
           }


           var action = "PHP URL"; 
           var imgAlt = attrs.imgAlt || 'Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure!';
           var cancel_return = $rootScope.baseUrl + "#/failure";
           var success_return = $rootScope.baseUrl + "#/success";

           var imgSrc = 'http://www.paypalobjects.com/' + languageCode + '/i/btn/btn_buynow_' + buttonSize + '.gif';
           var template =
                   '<form name="_xclick" action="' + action + '" method="post">' +
                   '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">' +     
                   '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="' + cancel_return + '">' +
                   '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' + success_return + '">' +
                   '<input type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="SUBSCRIBE">' +
                   '</form>';

           element.append(template);
       }
   };}])
   ```
2. put dirctive in html "payu-money-button"
3. in your controller file just put print $_POST and die it. you will find all your data.

Comment: Thanks for this, but can i some code or example, as not get u exactly

Comment: set all your parameters in directive code and if data are from html then you can pass data in directive "<payu-money-button anguage-code="en_US" currency-code="USD"   action=""  imgAlt="{{imgAlt}}" >
                    </payu-money-button>"
You can also define your parameter from html as well and then in your PHP server side you have do follow the steps for the payUmoney has given.

Comment: Sorry to say, but not getting you. As to send the all parameter to directive some diff. so any sample file or code will great help Thanks @Nitin

Comment: do you want code of PHP??
in angular side i have did only two things one is created directive and another in html put that directive  and if we have a json data then we can pass in html and get it in directive and if we have some fixed data then we can assign directly in directive.
except this two we don't need to do any thing in angular it will work definately 
The code what i have provided that is working example in my system.

Comment: if you want php code then i have that for the paypal not for payu so i haven't that code over here

Comment: Yes please provide me that code, based on that i will try for the payumoney. It will be a great help. Thanks@nitin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118423/discussion-between-nitin-agarwal-and-nitin).